# Вывести каждое слово из файла с новой строки в терминал

Tags: python

Я хочу каждое слово в тексте вывести отдельно на новой строке. Например, у меня есть файл 1.txt, в котором записан текст в строки. Написал код, но не могу понять в чем проблема

```
user = input('Введите полный путь к файлу:')
file = open(user, 'r+', encoding='utf-8')
print(*file.split(" "))
file.close()
```

Comment: Уточните свою проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user = input('Введите полный путь к файлу:')
file = open(user, 'r+', encoding='utf-8')
print(*file.read().split(" "), sep='\n')
file.close()
```

**Пояснение:**

1. Не `file.split(" ")`, а `file.read().split(" ")`
2. Добавьте перенос строки в print: `print(..., sep='/n')`

Если нужно сохранить вывод в новый файл с запросом его имени, то вот так:

```
source_filename = input('Введите путь к файлу: ')
target_filename = input('Имя файла куда сохранить: ')

with open(source_filename, 'r') as f:
    words = '\n'.join(f.read().split())

with open(target_filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(words)
```

Comment: И чтобы сохранить результат консоли, а должен использовать вместо read, write. Но вот как сохранить его в отдельный новый файл?

Comment: Похоже, вы не указали, что нужно сохранить в новый файл. Обновил ответ)

Comment: with open(input('Введите имя файла и формат:'), 'w') as f:
    f.write(words)
Я вот так еще дописал, чтобы юзер сам вводил нужное имя. И чтобы запросить у юзера адрес куда сохранить, мы используем f.save(input'Куда сохранить') или что-то путаю?

Comment: Поправил с учетом указания целевого файла

Comment: Можно вот так: `print(*file.read().split(" "), sep='\n', file=open("newfile.txt"))`